# HttpOnly Cookie not working when I use the domain attribute with a subdomain value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, webseal

I am using ExpressJS to serve this cookie back like so:
res.cookie('x-customer', access_token, { maxAge: 1200000, httpOnly: true, domain: 'abc.com.au', secure: true })

In my local, I am using NGINX proxy and it works fine, this response sets my cookie just fine:

1. the Chrome Devtools > Network >  Cookie tab shows Response is setting it
   [image]
2. the Chrome Devtools > Network > Headers tab shows the Reponse having Set-Cookie
   [image]

However, as soon as I move this to TEST environment, it no longer sets the cookie:

1. the Chrome Devtools > Network >  Cookie tab does not even show Response
   [image]
2. the Chrome Devtools > Network > Headers tab has missing Response Set-Cookie
   [image]

Then if I remove the domain attribute and deploy to TEST, the cookie starts to appear and Response is able to set it, but is not right solution because I need to specify a domain attribute so that subdomain such as site1.abc.com.au and site2.abc.com.au will be able to read the cookie.

**UPDATE 1: Even if I change domain attribute to have the exact domain as origin, it still doesn't work; as sson as I have domain attribute present in the cookie then it stops working in TEST only environment**

**UPDATE 2: I think the Test env uses Webseal or Isam or something like so, might it be the one blocking/dropping the cookie?**

Can you please help and let me know where is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Webseal. The default settings cause the issue.
They had to use

```
validate-backend-domain-cookies:no
```